# Node.js app is getting crashed while creating index on AWS EC2 instance but working properly on my local PC

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is the model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let locationSchema = new Schema({
  'locationTitle': String,
  'googlePlaceId': {
    'type': String,
    'unique': true
  },
  'coordinates': {
    'type': [Number],
    'index': '2dsphere'
  }, // longitude, latitude
}, {
  'timestamps': true
});

mongoose.model('Location', locationSchema);

mongoose.model('Location').collection.createIndex({ 'googlePlaceId': 1 }, { 'unique': 1});
```

Above is the model of the Location
I've made googlePlaceId as an Index with unique: true

And here is the Error:

```
You have triggered an unhandledRejection, you may have forgotten to catch a Promise rejection:
2|xplr     | MongoError: The field 'retryWrites' is not valid for an index specification. Specification: { name: "googlePlaceId_1", key: { googlePlaceId: 1 }, unique: 1, retryWrites: true }
2|xplr     |     at /var/xplr/xplr-api/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:581:63
2|xplr     |     at authenticateStragglers (/var/xplr/xplr-api/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:504:16)
2|xplr     |     at Connection.messageHandler (/var/xplr/xplr-api/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:540:5)
2|xplr     |     at emitMessageHandler (/var/xplr/xplr-api/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:310:10)
2|xplr     |     at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (/var/xplr/xplr-api/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:453:17)
2|xplr     |     at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
2|xplr     |     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:188:7)
2|xplr     |     at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
2|xplr     |     at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
2|xplr     |     at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:559:20)
```

I have tried making retryWrites explictly false but it still give me an error.
When I try to run my app on localhost its working properly.
I have no idea why it's creating a problem when I'm deploying it on AWS

Can you please suggest me any way to get rid of this?

Comment: In EC2 instance `locationSchema ` DB have duplicate record with `googlePlaceId `.

Answer (score 0):

It is clearly saying that the promise failure is not handled,

and the reason for that is, when you are trying to insert a record for which googlePlaceId is not unique it throws an error because of your unique index and that error is not handled in the promise that you had written in your code.

Hence only crashing after the unique index and working fine without it.